# Module loading in Strawberry Perl 5.24.0 is slow

Tags: perl, ftp, perl-module

I am using `Strawberry Perl 5.24.0` and I am loading the modules using the "`use`". For example, `use Net::FTP`.

But module loading is taking a lot of time at compile time. For example, loading the `Net::FTP` module is taking around **2.44s** in total (Below is the call trace which I got by using NYTProf). Can you please let me know that how can I improve the performance at compile time? Thanks!

**Subroutines:**

```
Net::SSLeay::RAND_poll (xsub)    (2.29s)
IO::Socket::SSL::BEGIN@20        (54.2ms)
Net::FTP::BEGIN@32               (42.1ms)
```

Comment: It's a problem in initializing the state of the random generator in Windows. See [Bug #103840 for Net-SSLeay: Slow initialization of secure communications in Strawberry Perl 5.18.1 and 5.20.2](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=103840).